# Как сложить значения внутри большого массива, который состоит из множества объектов? (решено, ответ в codepan)

Tags: javascript, массивы

(решено, ответ в codepan) Сложно описать задачу, но я попробую :)

Создал https://codepen.io/Spawnes/pen/LYmVMJj в котором размести большой массив данных.
Описание задачи здесь продублирую:

Нужно прибавить значения `X` со всеми последующими `X`

Нужно прибавить значения `Y` со всеми последующими `Y`

Нужно прибавить значения `marker.color` со последующими всеми `marker.color`

Чтобы по итогу получилось:

```
1) 1 кадр без изменений
2) На втором кадре всё, что было в первом + данные со второго.
3) На третьем кадре сумма 1 и 2 + новые данные с третьего кадра.
4) На четвёртом кадре предудыщий резльтат + данные с 4 кадра
```

И так далее

Добавлю ещё скриншот с демонстрацией самих данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, там достаточно много объектов внутри. И нужно просто сделать прибавление с сохранением предыдущих вычислений.

```
1 + 2 = 3. 

3 + 2 = 5

5 + 6 = 11

11 + 2 = 13
```

Comment: Вы правы, описание совершенно не понятно, но Вам скорее всего нужен .reduce или рекусивная функция, которая обойдёт массив или массивы

Comment: Вы правы. Мне помог очень умный человек) В CodePan добавил решение.